# Images don't show after eclipse project export as jar

Tags: java, eclipse, image, export, executable-jar

Help please, I am new to programming and have built a little tennis app. The game works when i run it through eclipse, however, when I export it as a jar the images don't show.
I have a class just for the images with a static method.

```
public static Image getImage(String fileName){
    Image img = null;
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return img;     
}
```

My folder structure is like this.

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn4VT.jpg)

The get image is called from various classes. Below is an example of how its called.

```
public Ball(double x, double y){
    super(x,y,BALL_DIAMETER, BALL_DIAMETER);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    //Get the image.
    imgBall = Images.getImage("src/resources/ball.png");
}//End of constructor
```

Thanks for any help much appreciated

I have tried this in the image class but it didn't work.

```
public static Image getImage(String fileName){
    Image img = null;
    URL url = Images.class.getResource(fileName);
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return img;     
}
```

Comment: Did you search on this first? Please do so as this gets asked often. The answer is the same -- jar files don't hold true "files" so get your images as resources. How is explained in hundreds or thousands of duplicate question answers.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have had a look at the post that you sent to me but that didn't work for me as my image method is static.

Comment: Your comment makes no sense as static has nothing to do with the issue, your problem or the solution, other than you have to get a reference to the class loader from the Class itself.

Comment: You use the class name to get the resource. Keep looking. Your Google skills need the exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your input. not sure how helpful it was. However, your sarcasm did put a smile on my face.

Comment: `Images.class.getResource(....)` ... etc

Comment: thanks i have tried that but doesn't seem to work. I have added the code change to the original post.